# TAPI 3.0 Call ID?

Tags: tapi

Does anyone know where I can find a unique identifier for a phone call using the Microsoft TAPI 3.0 library? I've tried `get_CallInfoLong(CALLINFO_LONG.CALLID)` but it always returns 0.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

CallID (and RelatedCallID) is not supported by most telephony hardware. Some TSPs for PBX systems support CallID, for example Panasonic KX-TDA series, but majority do not. If your telephony hardware doesn't support CallID, your only option is to assign your own unique identifier to all calls (GUID for example) in your code and carefully track the calls through their lifecycle. You have to make sure it's the same call so you don't assign new id to the same call. That's what our library does when CallID is not supported by the hardware.